# change a specific Picture in menu

Tags: asp.net, html

Hi If any of you know how to change a specific Picture on ohver  at menuItem in  menu control
 the code is like this

```
  <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" 
         EnableViewState="False"  IncludeStyleBlock="False">
 <Items>
 <asp:MenuItem  NavigateUrl="~/Homepage.aspx"  ImageUrl="~/images/ONE.png" ></asp:MenuItem>
 <asp:MenuItem  NavigateUrl="~/AboutUs.aspx" ImageUrl="~/images/SOME.png"></asp:MenuItem>
 <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/ContactUs.aspx" ImageUrl="~/images/MENU.png"></asp:MenuItem>
 </Items>

  </asp:Menu>
```

Please show an example, thanks  Please ,Please,Please,Please, I need it

Answer (score 0):

You Looking to change this in the page code behind, and when are you trying to do this, on mouse hover or..?

If done in code behind:

```
NavigationMenu.Items[0].ImageUrl = "whatever.jpg";
```

Comment: To complement your answer, it could also be done with CSS, by defining a class with a `background-image` style, and attributing that class to the menu item from codebehind.